# How do I define required properties of a referenced component in openapi 3.0?

Tags: swagger, openapi

I refer to an other component, and some of its fields become required.

Example with AbstractQuestion, a component that I will refer to later on:

```
  AbstractQuestion:
        type: object
        properties:
            title:
                description: Question statement
                type: string
            label:
                description: Question label
                type: string
            required:
                description: whether an answer is required for this question or if it could be left blank
                type: boolean
            question_type:
                description: campaign type
                enum:
                    - profile
                    - feeling
                type: string
            answer_type:
                enum:
                    - string
                    - list
                    - date
                type: string
            max_length:
                description: >-
                    for open ended questions this is the max characters possible. for list type questions
                    this would be the max number of options to select when multiple answers are accepted
                type: integer
            modelizable:
                description: 'whether the questions'' answers are suitable for feeding ML models (e.g. 1,2,3,4)'
                type: boolean
            choices:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/QuestionChoices'
```

Now, I will use it to define a Post request body, specifying which field are required. NB: I didn't specify this in the previous object because it is also used in an other context (GET or PUT requests for example) where those fields are not required.

```
    QuestionPost:
      allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/AbstractQuestion'
      required:
          - title
          - label
          - required
          - question_type
          - answer_type
          - modelizable
```

When I try this solution, my tests do not pass, as they match the yaml file to my api and find this error:

```
openapi_spec_validator.exceptions.ExtraParametersError: Required list has not defined properties: ['label', 'title', 'answer_type', 'question_type', 'modelizable', 'required']
```

It seems unable to find the required properties in the referenced component.

When I try this solution:

```
    QuestionPost:
      $ref: '#/components/schemas/AbstractQuestion'
      required:
          - title
          - label
          - required
          - question_type
          - answer_type
          - modelizable
```

I get a warning in my editor. My understanding of the doc is that the required field will be ignored.

Maybe what I'm trying to achieve is just not possible? How would you do it?

Comment: Your definition with `allOf` and `required` is correct. Just in case, try moving `required` _inside_ `allOf` as a second item, some tools don't like keywords _alongside_ `allOf`. If this does not help, file a bug report with the openapi_spec_validator project.

Comment: movin required inside the allof solved the problem.

Comment: corresponding issue: https://github.com/p1c2u/openapi-spec-validator/issues/27